# $watch got unexpected multiple events in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am trying to use AngularJS and moment.js in-order to format time after the json data loaded, and I used $watch to monitor the $scope.comments, but not sure why the $watch recognized 3 events (the result set from json contains 3 items) instead of 1-time as I expected. The console.lof('changed') has been executed 3 tiem

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ng', 'commentController']);
MyApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/comment-list.html',
            controller: 'CommentListCtrl'
        });
    }
]);

MyApp.directive("timeago", function () {
    return function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.$watch("comments", function () {
            $('.timeago').each(function (index) {
                console.log('chaneged');
                $(this).removeClass('timeago');
                var time = moment($(this).text());
                //console.log(time.fromNow());
                $(this).text(time.fromNow());
            })
        });
    };
});

/* Controllers */
var commentController = angular.module('commentController', []);
commentController.controller('CommentListCtrl', function CommentListCtrl($http, $scope) {
    $scope.comments = [];

    $http.get('/api/json?n=3').success(function (data) {
        $scope.commentsLoaded(data);
    });

    $scope.commentsLoaded = function (data, status) {
        $scope.comments = data;
    }

});
```

and the template:

```
<div ng-Controller="CommentListCtrl">
    <ul class="comments" timeago>
        <li ng-repeat="comment in comments">        
            <span class="timeago">{{comment.time}}</span>
            <p>{{comment.content}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the reason $watch executes 3 times is:

- The first time it executes is on startup, where `newValue == undefined`
- The second time is when you call this line: `$scope.comments = [];`
- The third time is when the json is received: `$scope.comments = data;`

It has nothing to do with your json has 3 items.

> however, not sure why the console.log($(this).text()); after the data
>   loaded only get this : {{comment.time}} It seems that the event was
>   catched before the template rendered

Because at the time, angular does not update its bindings yet and ***the view is not updated***.

For separations of concern and how we should work with mvc structure like angular, view is for displaying, you should not access data from there, access it though model instead. In your case, you're trying to format the display, it should be the job of a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters)

Write a filter like this:

```
angular.module('commentController').
  filter('dateFormat', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return moment(input).fromNow();
    }
  });
```

Use it in HTML, don't need `timeago` directive:

```
<div ng-Controller="CommentListCtrl">
    <ul class="comments">
        <li ng-repeat="comment in comments">        
            <span class="timeago">{{comment.time | dateFormat }}</span>
            <p>{{comment.content}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Khanh, actually, I tried reduced the json return by 2 items and the console.log just executed only 2 times. I think the $watch has observed beyond the $scope.comments. I known the issue happened for the view, any solution to make the jquery run after the view is updated? Thanks

Comment: @mrblue: sorry, did not look at it carefully. `console.log('changed')` is inside `$('.timeago').each`. But why do you need to access the DOM directly like this. For separations of concern and how we should work with mvc structure like angular, view is for displaying, you should not access data from there, access it though model instead.

Comment: hi Khanh, it works perfectly. thanks so much. it's nice to meet a Vietnamese, btw ;)

Answer (score 1):

The watch method takes a function with 2 arguments (newValue,oldValue). You can check these values when the watch is executed.

```
 $scope.$watch("comments", function (newValue,oldValue) {
```

From what i can tell, the first time it executes is on setup, where oldValue is `null`. Then on any other assignment. Check the values and you would know.

To handle it correctly put checks like

```
if(newValue && newValue!=oldValue) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: adding to chandermani solution you could  also use if(newvalue===oldvalue) return

Comment: hi Chandermani, it worked, the system recognized only one change, however, not sure why the console.log($(this).text()); after the data loaded only get this : {{comment.time}} It seems that the event was catched before the template rendered.

Comment: I think i know why you console.log is inside a jquery selector.`$('.timeago')` is returning 3 elements.

Comment: @mrblue:actually, The watch method takes a function with 3 arguments (newValue,oldValue,scope)

Comment: @Chandermani, would you like to explain me and suggest a solution to makr it works? Thanks so much.

Comment: That type of solution you are looking for. Your initial question was why console log comes 3 times. Can you explain what you want to do so that we can help you better. If you want to execute the code on the specific element only use the `element` parameter, this is the dom object on which the directive was defined.